# Copy subversion working tree without files and repopulate it

Tags: svn

I'm migrating to a new computer at work and I have a handful of SVN working trees in my documents folders. Conforming to [the first great virtue of a programmer](http://threevirtues.com/), I am lazy and don't want to have to track down what repos I had checked out and do it all over again manually, but I don't want to have to copy multiple gigabytes over the network by copying entire working trees (and .svn/pristine in each working tree).

<del>Can I just copy the .svn dotfolder without the pristines and run `svn update` when I'm on my new machine to have it fetch the trunk's latest revision? Or will that miserably break it and I'm stuck manually noting what repositories I had checked out? Or is there another feature of SVN that can accomplish this that I'm unaware of?</del>

Is there any way to be able to copy working tree metadata (i.e. the remote repository location) from one folder to another without actual file content, thus allowing someone to have an empty working tree folder that can be populated from the repo (e.g. via `svn update`)?

Comment: There's no feature of SVN that would do this. Try it and let us know. Be warned that even if this somehow worked, mucking about in the `.svn` folder is not supported and could break with the next version.

Comment: Sadly, copying the dotfolder without the `pristine` and `tmp` directories doesn't work. It complains about missing `svn-base` files when I try to do any operation. I'm a little surprised that there isn't a way to just copy working tree metadata around, but on the other hand I suppose I've been spoiled by dependency tracking in `npm` and `composer`.

Comment: Ah well.  Maybe a feature request for SVN? Export an existing checkout's metadata?